# Pagination output laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm a beginner in Laravel.

I need Paginate my Table with Data. Can't understand how setup links. I'm trying to search some documentation but don't understand how I can do this.

My Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = Viewers::all()->forPage(1, 5)->sortByDesc('last_activity');
        $users->setPath('/admin');
        return view('pages.admin.dashboard', ['users'=>$users]);
    }
```

My `dashboard.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
    <div class="content">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">#</th>
                <th>IP</th>
                <th>Request URI</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Device</th>
                <th>Last Activity</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">{{$user->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->ip_address}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->request_uri}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->country}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->city}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->device}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->last_activity}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Please review the documentation on Pagination: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination. This should be as simple as `$users = Users::orderBy('last_activity', 'DESC')->paginate(100);`, then `$users->links()` in your view. Sidenote, don't use `User::all()` unless you want *all* users. Loading them into memory to then sort is inefficient compared to a database sort.

Comment: Change this line to `$users = Viewers::sortByDesc('last_activity')->paginate(10);` Now just put this code `{{ $users->links() }}` under the foreach loop

Comment: @sta `'Call to undefined method App/Viewers::sortByDesc()'`. You're mistaking `Builder` and `Collection` methods. Models queries, which are `Builder` instances until a closure is passed, do not have `sortBy()` or `sortByDesc()`, you need to use `orderBy()`. `Collection`s use `sortBy()`. Please review and correct your comment. https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderBy, https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_sortBy and https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_sortByDesc.

Comment: @Tim Lewis my silly mistake

Comment: @TimLewis add answer - I'll accepting that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Viewers::all()` loads every record in your database into a `Collection`. Collections have `sortBy()` and `sortByDesc()` methods, but Models, which are `Builder` instances while querying, have an `orderBy()` method. Using DB ordering will in most cases be more efficient than PHP/Laravel sorting, so try not to use `::all()` unless you need to.

With that being said, your query can be fixed to:

```
$users = Viewers::orderBy('last_activity', 'DESC')->paginate(100); // Replace 100 with desired number per page
```

Then, in your `.blade.php` file, use the `links()` method available on Pagination instances:

```
{{ $users->links() }}
```

That will output First, Previous, Page(s), Next and Last links, based on the number of records per page.